# how do i select character from left side excluding .txt at right side

Tags: database, oracle

The column have a not uniform data, some have ".txt" at the end. 
Consider one of the entries as "ABCDEFG.TXT"
i want my select statement to return me "ABCDEFG".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check how to create How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so that you can get a much better response to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with demo (text) as
     ( select 'ABCDEFG.TXT' from dual union all
       select 'HIJKL' from dual )
select text
     , regexp_replace(text, '\.TXT$')
from   demo;

TEXT         REGEXP_REPLACE(TEXT,'\.TXT$')
------------ --------------------------------------------
ABCDEFG.TXT  ABCDEFG
HIJKL        HIJKL
```

Or if you need it to be case-insensitive:

```
with demo (text) as
     ( select 'ABCDEFG.TXT' from dual union all
       select 'abcdefg.txt' from dual union all
       select 'HIJKL' from dual )
select text
     , regexp_replace(text, '\.TXT$', '', 1, 1, 'i') as replaced
from   demo;

TEXT         REPLACED
------------ --------------------------------------------
ABCDEFG.TXT  ABCDEFG
abcdefg.txt  abcdefg
HIJKL        HIJKL
```

Or to strip any three-character file extension:

```
regexp_replace(text, '\....$', '', 1, 1, 'i')
```

Or to strip any extension of any length:

```
regexp_replace(text, '\.[^.]*$', '', 1, 1, 'i')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Query will be helpful

```
DECLARE @Var NVARCHAR(50)
SET @Var = 'ABCDASDFASF.txt'

SELECT LEFT(@Var, CHARINDEX('.', @Var)-1) 'Filename'
```

Ouput:

```
Filename
--------------------------------------------------
ABCDASDFASF

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Good to know, but the OP asked for an Oracle solution.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Yes, tagged `Sql` also. Hence I answered. Sorry for Inconvenience.

Comment: Well there’s SQL and there’s SQL :) Maybe it will help someone else though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use combination of `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`, it is more efficient than `REGEXP_` functions.

This works even if you have multiple dot `"."` in your text. It searches for the last dot. If you need to consider all type of extensions, search for `'.'` instead of `'.TXT'` . You should then search for `CASE WHEN txt LIKE '%.%'` as a general case.

```
SELECT
   CASE
      WHEN
         INSTR ( upper(txt) , '.TXT' ) > 0 
      THEN
         SUBSTR(txt, 1, INSTR ( txt, '.' , - 1 ) - 1 ) 
      ELSE
         txt 
   END
   modtxt 
FROM
   yourtable;
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/live/MDCOE94673)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
select
    case
        when upper(file_name) like '%.TXT' then substr(file_name, 1, (length(file_name) - 4))
        else file_name
    end  cleaned_file_name
from
    file_names;
```

Test:

```
create table file_names
(
    file_name     varchar2(30)
);

insert into file_names (file_name) values ('ABCDEFG');
insert into file_names (file_name) values ('ABCDEFG.TXT');
insert into file_names (file_name) values ('ABCDEFGTXT');
insert into file_names (file_name) values ('ABCD.TXT.EFG');
insert into file_names (file_name) values ('abcdefg.txt');
insert into file_names (file_name) values ('ABCDEFG.DOC');

select
    case
        when upper(file_name) like '%.TXT' then substr(file_name, 1, (length(file_name) - 4))
        else file_name
    end  cleaned_file_name
from
    file_names;

CLEANED_FILE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFGTXT
ABCD.TXT.EFG
abcdefg
ABCDEFG.DOC

6 rows selected.
```